# running npm install deletes "packages" object from package-lock.json file

Tags: angular, npm

Can't find much info on this.

When running npm install, with an updated package.json file with 2 new added dependencies, the entire "packages" object gets removed automatically from the package-lock.json file.

Is there any good explanation for this? Below is an example of where the packages object is located within package-lock.json:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {blah} (REMOVED AFTER NPM INSTALL)
  "dependencies":{blah}
```

Thank you

When discarding the package-lock.json changes, delete node modules, and re running npm install, the same behavior happens again where "packages" object gets deleted.

Comment: Typically that's my philosophy with this file. But it seemed worrisome that half of my package-lock.json file was deleted based off an npm install command. I can't find a ton of info on the "packages" object found within package-lock.json but it seems important.